How influences a Javascript redirect without status code change crawling and indexing?
We have a category page with linked products. Linked products are usual a href links to pages like

Category: /category
Product: /product1

After clicking /product1 there is a Javascript redirect to /product1?param=1. The status code remains 200.
All menus, internal links and sitemap contain primary urls, /product1.
Q: What influence has such redirect on crawling and indexing?

This would not be a positive for crawling in general, but if you only care about Google it could be OK but it officially considered considered "not a good idea"
According to https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157 "The redirects were quickly followed by Google. From an indexing standpoint, they were interpreted as 301s — the end-state URLs replaced the redirected URLs in Google’s index."
That said, Google advises not to do Javascript Redirects if you can avoid it - see https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/301-redirects - so this is definately not a best practice.    Also see https://www.searchenginejournal.com/javascript-redirects-for-seo/462072/ which has a quote from a Google representatives that says "Js redirects are probably not a good idea".
